# How to hide blocks based on content type or for specific nodes?

Tags: blocks

In some of my nodes I need to show only "body" part of node. I don't want to show blocks etc. in those nodes. How can I do this ?

- Create a new "content type" and put the data from existing nodes to that type of node. And excluding that "content type" from each of the blocks.
- By using javascript/jquery like: `$('div'.block).remove()`

Any more elegant answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer very much depends on how the nodes you want to show only bodies of are different from all other nodes of same content type.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Create a new content type and [convert](http://drupal.org/project/node_convert) all the nodes you want to it. Then you can specify in blocks visibility settings not to show blocks on the nodes of that content type and create a new template for this content type in which only body is printed.
2. Another way is to give the [context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) a try. The context module provides a much more flexible way to control blocks visibility so you can specify different contexts for your normal nodes (and assign blocks to this context) and your no-blocks nodes with no blocks assigned.

I'm sure there must be other ways to accomplish this, but these two are the first things I thought of :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new content type, just for this, seems like something you should try to avoid (the number of content types should always be reduced where possible). These days there is another alternative available: use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) intercept the situation where someone uses an URL that corresponds to "*some of your nodes*" (as in your question), so that the block is NOT shown for those nodes.

For that, create a Rules Component with a Rules Condition that performs a *Text comparison* with `Parameter: Text: [site:current-page:path]` and an appropriate *Matching Text* for the URLs like "NOT (`node/nid1` AND  `node/nid2`)", whereas `nid1` and `nid2` or the node ids of nodes for which the blocks should not be shown.